# Oceans ー Thick or Big?

Tags: words, etymology, homophonic-kanji

Straightforward question.  The Pacific Ocean is `太平洋【たい・へい・よう】` and the Atlantic Ocean is `大西洋【たい・せい・よう】`.  What was the reasoning in using a different character for the `たい` in each?  And why `太` for Pacific and `大` for Atlantic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the characters clearly suggest, 大西洋 simply refers to the big Western ocean. Not much confusion there.

太平洋, however, is an adaptation of the English "Pacific" Ocean. 太平 is a word in its own right that means roughly this: "peaceful" or "tranquil," or "pacific," if you will. According to the page linked at the bottom it had previously been known as 大東海.

It seems like 太 may be a simplified form of 泰, although apparently this isn't listed in all character dictionaries (note that [here](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1316862793) a person claims to have found it). The word 泰平 exists and is the same word as 太平, and based purely on shape it makes sense that one would be a 略字. So if this theory is to be believed then the 太 in 太平洋 does *not* mean thick/fat, but rather peace as in 泰平, because 泰 simplifies to 太, and is not to be confused with Thailand.

Lengthy discussion about it can be found here! http://homepage2.nifty.com/osiete/s539.htm

Comment: 泰平 is a word? In Chinese we only say 太平; 泰 in compounds does mean "peace" though.

Comment: That's an awesome explanation. How do people know these things?

Comment: @user54609 perhaps 太平 is the simplified version in Chinese also? Or is it that way in traditional as well? I find it interesting, though, that they used a simplified version of the character for 太平洋, but the original kanji exists in other words like 安泰, and on its own is the kanji for Thailand.

Comment: 泰 is not simplified to 太. 泰 is used widely on its own in set expressions, and also with referral to Thailand. in fact, the character on its own would probably be an abbreviation for Thailand.

Comment: Found this site where a person asks about finding it in "大漢和辞典" http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1316862793

Comment: Another downvote here apparently. Explanation as to why?

Comment: @user54609 According to this dictionary, Chinese also used 泰平 in the past. http://images.gg-art.com/dictionary/ ② 安定平和 [peaceful]
泰，安也。——《字汇》
宇泰定者，发乎天光。——《庄子·庚桑楚》
泰而不骄，威而不猛。——《论语·尧曰》
以祈国泰民安。——吴自牧《梦梁录》
家贫躬耕，粟熟则食粟，…处之泰然也。——《元史·许衡传》
否泰如天地。——《玉台新咏·古诗为焦仲卿妻作》
如:泰日(天下太平的时代) 泰治(太平安定) 泰定(安定) 泰和(太平) 泰平(政教清平，国泰民安。即太平) 泰通(国泰政通)

Comment: Chronologically this is very strange. Japan probably had a word for 'Pacific Ocean' 2000 years ago (it's not like it's something they imported recently). Why would Japanese (and Chinese and Korean, according to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/太平洋)) import that word from English, rather than English from the people who actually live right next to it?

Comment: 太 and 泰 are the same word, but their shapes are not derived from each other. 太 is derived from one or two marks added to 大. 泰 is derived from two 大 side by side (now written ) and a 水 (氺).

Comment: @MathieuBouville the assumption that Japan had a word for Pacific Ocean 2000 years ago is kind coming from our modern perspective, where we categorize bodies of water the way we are familiar with now. Until relatively recently in history, Japan did not refer to "the Pacific Ocean" as one entity, but to areas of ocean or sea based on what part of land they were near.